# (Xcode) Permission denied with iCloud enabled

Tags: xcode, macos, icloud, permission-denied, key-value-store

If I activate iCloud Key-Value Store and add a iCloud container I get an error "Permission denied" while trying to launch my (mac) app. But why?

The App ID is enabled for iCloud (Production & Development) and I generated and installed new profiles (Production & Development) after I enabled the App ID for iCloud.

I've done this many times with iOS Apps and all worked. So where's the mistake?

Comment: I'm currently having this same issue. I can enable iCloud without problems, but if I add key-value store or ubiquity container identifiers, I get Permission Denied.

Comment: After a little more guesswork, I was able to solve my issue. It seems that I was using the wrong developer profile to sign the application -- you must sign with the dev profile that matches the provisioning profile for the device (in this case the mac).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.  Solved mine by fixing typo in company identifier.

When I built the profile, I used net.company (all lower case).  When starting my code in Xcode, I used net.Company  (note the caps).

When I started a new program, I used the same capitalization as the profile.  My compile worked.